# как в maven при сборке модуля передать параметр?

Tags: java, maven

Есть pom, собирается так:
   mvn package -P 01-AAA -Dprovider=BBB
Как его собрать модулем из другого pom.xml

```
  <module>test</module>
```

С передачей параметров -P и -D?

Comment: как собрать написано в самом вопросе, правда не понятна роль модуля test ? поясните суть действа

Comment: Данный POM нужно собрать из другого pom.xml как модуль, то есть:
    <modules>

        <module>test</module>

    </modules>

Но как в таком случае передать параметры?

Comment: Помы пишутся (руками), модули собираются.. Модули собираются все вместе или каждый по отдельности (один за раз).  Как правило, все параметры задаются из командной строки. Не совсем понятно какие параметры откуда и куда нужно передавать ?